# Binary Search Tree order of insert when we have an estimate ahead of time

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search-tree

I am currently reading "Algorithms Fourth Edition" by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne. I have question about:

> 3.2.5 Suppose that we have an estimate ahead of time of how often search keys are to be accessed in a BST, and the freedom to insert items in any order that we desire. *Should the keys be inserted into the tree in increasing order, decreasing order of likely frequency of access, or some other order?* Explain your answer.

Obviously, the perfect situation is to have at root the item that is most accessed, then at its direct ancestors, the next items in terms of frequency of access and so on and so on.
However, this is BST and as such we have to insert them according to its specifics.
Shall I consider in this task all the combinations?

For example, if we have items 1 (accessed 1000 times), 2 (999 times) and 3 (999). The tree with root 2 and ancestors 1 and 3 is the best solution I think.
Its sounds logical to me, to strive to have balanced tree. However this again depends on the input. If we have smallest item accessed 10 000 times and next 10 items accessed only once, then the smallest shall be root and the tree will not 
be perfectly balanced.

I will also appreciate guidance, not direct answers.

Comment: probably related to [static optimal binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_binary_search_tree)

Comment: Thanks @juvian, optimal BST is exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Neither inserting the keys in increasing or decreasing order of likely frequency of access will be the optimal approach.
This problem is known as creating an optimal-binary search tree (Optimal BST).
For more details, refer to https://github.com/reneargento/algorithms-sedgewick-wayne/blob/master/src/chapter3/section2/Exercise5.txt